# How to get HTML5 audio duration time when the audio is paused

Tags: javascript, html

I am new on HTML5, What I want to do is get the audio duration time when I click the pause button

here is my code

```
<audio controls="" id="audio">
  <source src="assets/record_file/abc.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="assets/record_file/abc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element. Please try other latest browser
</audio>
```

any idea how to do it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('audio').pause = function() {
    var currentTime = document.getElementById('audio').currentTime;
    var duration = document.getElementById('audio').duration;
    alert(currentTime);
};
```

Please check [HTML Audio and Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp), describe all methods, properties and events.

Comment: those variables hold the currenttime of audio on which it is paused and total length of audio respectively.